# Close a branch with a colon ':' in the name

Tags: mercurial

I have a branch containing colon (':') in the name. How can I close it?

I can't fully update to it (the files in the directory do update after "hg up", though I get an error message "abort: ':' cannot be used in a name"; and "hg summary" shows the right revision number and tag, but the previous branch name). "hg ci --close-branch" exits with "abort: can only close branch heads".

I can recommit it this way changeset by changeset with a proper name and then prune the old one using clone or strip, but I wonder if there is another solution.

UPD I have used the workaround, but still want to know a straightforward solution, aslo someone else might find it helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mercurial's documentation is a bit misleading on this point: Colons in branch names are accepted, but when you try to use the name, it is misinterpreted as a revision range. To prevent hg from parsing `blah:blah` as a range, you can write it as `"branch('blah:blah')"`. For example:

```
hg log -r "branch('blah: blah')"
```

The above works on relatively recent versions of mercurial. It sounds like you have additional, version related problems, but give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but I was able to create a named branch with a colon in the name, update to it by revision number instead of name, and close it:

```
C:\temp>hg branches
blah:blah                      2:32fbac773905
default                        1:f132a6d0ce30

C:\temp>hg glog --template "{rev} {branch} {desc}\r\n"
o  2 blah:blah file3
|
| @  1 default file2
|/
o  0 default file1


C:\temp>hg update 2
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 1 files removed, 0 files unresolved

C:\temp>hg ci --close-branch -m closed

C:\temp>hg glog --template "{rev} {branch} {desc}\r\n"
@  3 blah:blah closed
|
o  2 blah:blah file3
|
| o  1 default file2
|/
o  0 default file1
```

Comment: I have a whitespace after the colon, if it might matter. I can not update by any means (tried id, branch name, revision number).
In my case this branch was created with mercurial-1.8, right now I have 2.2 and can't reproduce neither your example, nor the original broblem becasue branch name with colon ":" is no more allowed (issue3125).

Comment: I have 2.3.2 and was able to create the named branch "blah:blah" via `hg branch blah:blah` and committing, so maybe that is still a bug.  I was *not* able to make a branch name with space after it: `hg branch "blah: "`.  The space was stripped.  You might be able to do a branch rename via the `convert` extension.

Comment: @SD57: can you provide a link to issue3125 you are referencing? I'm seeing the same issue after updating to Mercurial 2.4

Comment: @dls What I found was [link](http://www.selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2011-November/035941.html) 
I now can't creat a branch with colon using mercurial-2.4 (gentoo), but did it with mercurial-1.8 (Fedora 14); I'm not sure whet the patch has been applied.